# subprocess.call with /key=val does not work

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am trying to execute following command on Windows. (command works in CMD)
`"D:\xxxx\tool.exe" /RunScript="C:\xxxx\scdm.py" /Headless=True /Splash=False /Welcome=False /ExitAfterScript=True /ScriptArgs="C:\xxx\file.sat"`

PS paths are shortened, if needed I can provide full paths

I am using subprocess.call but it seems like arguments are ignored

````
command = [scdm_dir, r'/RunScript="{}"'.format(scdm_script_path),
           r"/Headless=True", r"/Splash=False", r"/Welcome=False", r"/ExitAfterScript=True",
                  r'/ScriptArgs="{}"'.format(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Fluent", "fluent.sat"))]

  print(command)
  subprocess.call(command)```

output of print is:
>>> ['D:\xxxx\tool.exe', '/RunScript="C:\xxxx\scdm.py"', '/Headless=True', '/Splash=False', '/Welcome=False', '/ExitAfterScript=True', '/ScriptArgs="C:\xxx\file.sat"']
````

Comment: don't quote your filenames : `r'/ScriptArgs="{}"'` => `r'/ScriptArgs={}'`, same for "RunScript". And please post the error message you're getting. But the quotes are a clear error

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, you are right, thank  you!
unfortunately there was no error message, so I could not debug it properly

Comment: well, something has to be done about the error handling in `D:\xxxx\tool.exe` :)

Comment: If the argument has spaces in it, `subprocess.list2cmdline` (called internally) will automatically quote the entire argument, e.g. `'"/ScriptArgs=C:\\xxxx yyyy\\file.sat"'`. By mistakenly adding quotes manually, they get backslash-escaped as literal quote characters in the command line.